# "content" not displayed in inspect element (Chrome dev tool)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In **Chrome**'s inspect element, I see in some lectures that network tab can show you size/contents for images' (and etc) file size. But my window does not show "content" in it. Also the number in "size" seems to be a lot off from actual file size. Is there something I should do to display "contents"?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The size displayed in small rows is the gzipped size for transport. To get the content size enable large resource rows.

The large resource row toggle is found in the View options:

[image: Large Resource Rows Toggle]

Then the content size in gray appears below the transport size: [image: Actual Size Display]